# Why this if statement is not redudant in NetBeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans

I wrote a method in java class like this:

```
public boolean checkPlace() {
    if (this.PlaceName.equals("Name Place"))
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

I wonder why it is not redudant.

Could I write just return if statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which question are you asking 1)  "Is the `if` statement redundant?" or 2) "Shouldn't Netbeans have told me this `if` statement is redundant?"

Comment: A shot in the dark, but I think it is not redundant. `PlaceName` could be `null`, in which case a `NullPointerException` is thrown. So there's another outcome within that method. Try switching the two objects to `"Name Place".equals(PlaceName)`. Maybe then Netbeans will tell you that the `if-else` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
public boolean checkPlace() {
    return PlaceName.equals("Name Place");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is redundant in general. Best practice would be to write

```
if (this.PlaceName.equals("Name Place")) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Or if that is not just a dummy example

```
return this.PlaceName.equals("Name Place")
```

If you are more used to expression-like syntax from other languages, then Java does **not** allow you to write

```
return  if (this.PlaceName.equals("Name Place")) true else false;
```

However it does support ternary expressions in which case you have to be sure you only have 2 branches and not more.

```
return this.PlaceName.equals("Name Place") ? true : false;
```